postgres docker container bash script not replacing variable in sed
In my dockerized container I am unable to replace a variable using 'sed'.
These are my files:
myfile.sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${PG_TABLE}(...)

myscript.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "variable1=${1}"
echo "variable2=${2}"
sed  -i "s/\${$1}/$2/g" myfile.sql

run command
myscript.sh PG_TABLE "mytablename"

Actual:

echo variable1=PG_TABLE
echo variable2=mytablename
REPLACEMENT:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS (...)

Expected:

echo variable1=PG_TABLE
echo variable2=mytablename
REPLACEMENT
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytablename(...)

This is supposed to replace the placeholder with my variable 'mytablename', but it just replaces it with empty string.
Maybe its because of my container alpine version.
This is my os.
my docker build operating system
cat /etc/os-release


PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian


What do you get from commandline (not docker) when you change the last line in your myscript.sh with echo 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${PG_TABLE} (...)' | sed  "s/\${$1}/$2/g" and call it ./myscript.sh PG_TABLE "mytablename"?

@WalterA I get the intended result which is what I want. CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytablename (...). Its just not doing it in my program

Issue is with sed placeholder.
Use \${${1}} to match the placeholder in the myfile.sql
Here's the working solution, where running the container shows correct replacement.
myscript.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "variable1=${1}"
echo "variable2=${2}"
echo "Running sed command..."
echo "sed -i \"s/\\\${${1}}/${2}/g\" /app/myfile.sql"
sed -i "s/\${${1}}/${2}/g" /app/myfile.sql
cat /app/myfile.sql

myfile.sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${PG_TABLE}(...);

Dockerfile
FROM debian:bookworm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sed

COPY myfile.sql /app/myfile.sql
COPY myscript.sh /app/myscript.sh

WORKDIR /app

RUN chmod +x myscript.sh

CMD ["./myscript.sh", "PG_TABLE", "mytablename"]


docker build -t sed-replacement .
docker run --rm sed-replacement

OUTPUT
variable1=PG_TABLE
variable2=mytablename
Running sed command...
sed -i "s/\${PG_TABLE}/mytablename/g" /app/myfile.sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytablename(...);


ok I made a mistake. The reason it didn't work is because I was expecting the arg to exist in my docker-compose file and it wasn't. Therefore the replacement was empty "". Adding in that arg
docker-compose.yml
...
    build:
      context: .
      args:
       - PG_DB=${PG_DB}
       - PG_TABLE=${PG_TABLE} # Needed to pass variable to Dockerfile during 

Dockerfile
# ...
FROM postgres
ARG PG_DB #  Need to recieve arg
ARG PG_TABLE

ADD seed.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/seed.sql

COPY script.sh .
RUN chmod +x script.sh

# Need to pass arg to script
RUN ./script.sh PG_DB "${PG_DB}" PG_TABLE "${PG_TABLE}" 

